# Associations Class (List in a List)

Tags: c#, forms, list, class

I have 2 classes associated with one and other, a Town has many People in it.

```
public class Town
{
    List<People> collectionOfPeople;

    public string town { get; set; }

    public Town()
    {
        townName = "";

        collectionOfPeople = new List<People>();
        collectionOfPeople.Add(new People());
    }

    public Town(string tmp_townName)
    {
        townName = tmp_townName;

        collectionOfPeople = new List<People>();
        collectionOfPeople.Add(new People("Daniel Smith", "22"));
    }
}
```

After constructing an instance of a Town in a List, and a record associated with it I'd like to display the result on a Form.

```
    private int numberOfPeople;
    private int currentPeopleShown;
    private int numberOfTown;
    private int currentTown;
    private List<People> peopleList;
    private List<Town> townList;

    // ************************* Methods/Functionality
    private void LoadData()
    {
        txt_townName.Text = (townList[0]).townName;
        txt_peopleName.Text = (peopleList[currentPeopleShown]).name;

        numberOfPeople = peopleList.Count();
        currentPeopleShown = 0;
    }
```

How would I reference a List inside a List, to display or count the number of records within it (town0 .. show people1, 2, 3 etc)?

Comment: You mean a [nested list](http://www.dotnetperls.com/nested-list)?

Comment: If you want just to display the items of list you can just iterate through them with a for or a foreach loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to expose the list as a property

```
public List<People> CollectionOfPeople { get; set; }
^                                      ^ ^    ^    ^
```

And then reference it like:

```
var people = myTown.CollectionOfPeople;
```

Comment: Could you narrow down where I would make the change?

Both of the classes are located in separate cs files, and cause problems when I edit them.

Comment: See my update (I added some tick marks to indicate the changes required).

Comment: When I change the Town class List<People> it flags an error on the constructors below. "Does not exist in context etc"

Comment: Well, I haven't given you the *exact* code changes that you need, because I don't have your program's source code in front of me (please don't paste all of it here).  My answer is conceptual; I see in the code that you've shown us that `collectionOfPeople` is inaccessible, so I made it accessible.  Whether or not this is the correct solution for your needs is something that you're gonna have to figure out yourself.

Comment: I assumed I was typing it in the wrong place!.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use SelectMany(...) to merge all nested items into single enumberable

```
townList.SelectMany(t=>t.collectionOfPeople).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

> How would I reference a List inside a List, to display through or count the number of record within it. (town0 .. show people1,2,3 etc)

```
foreach (Town town in townList)
  foreach (People people in town.collectionOfPeople)
    MessageBox.Show(people.Name);
```